# What does it means "to use an ice cream"?

Tags: expressions, verbs

I heard this expression some days ago at work and couldn't understand what it means.

Two people in a conversation, talking about how bored they were on a Friday, then the guy just said

> I could use an ice cream right now, I mean, WHO couldn't use an ice cream now?.

Has anyone ever heard this expression before?

Comment: _wouldn't to use_? Are you sure that's what was said?

Comment: sorry, it was "who couldn't use an ice cream now?" lol

Comment: "I could use an X right now" means "I would like to have an X right now". (The expression isn't specific to ice-cream.) "I mean, WHO couldn't use an ice cream now?" is a rhetorical question meaning"everybody could use [would like] an ice-cream now". I'm not sure why you've capitalised "who" - in that sentence I would expect '"couldn't" to be the emphasised word.